# Could I use nested format character within format string in C?

Tags: c, nested, printf

Is it possible to form a format string having nested format character? That is, if I want to specify field width for a long integer with some width which in turn specified by an integer. See the illustration below

```
printf("%%dld", integer, long_integer);
```

Of course, it's a bad idea, but I want to know if there is any other way to perform something similar to this?

Comment: Although the duplicate question addresses strings, the basic answer (use `*` as part of the format string) is still valid.

Answer (score 2):

See the (POSIX) specification for [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html).  It pays you to read it, and re-read it, and re-re-read it, each year or so after you done it the first dozen or so times.  It is big, and complex, and you'll usually find something new each time — at least, that's how it works for me.

You can use:

```
printf("%*ld", integer, long_integer);
```

The `*` consumes an `int` value and allows you to specify the width of the field.